# How to check if all entries for a column in sql table is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    pid, first_name, last_name, middle_name, hcc_score (.. and so on)
    FROM (patient AS p JOIN patient_score AS s ON p.patient_id=s.patient_id);
```

Before running this query I need to write another query where I need to check if all the entries for a column X are null. This can be checked for multiple columns like first_name, last_name. If all the entries in a specific column are null, then I will mark this column as unavailable (hide it from my frontend table). If any of the entry is not null, then I will mark that column as available and display it in my table.

So far what I've tried is this but I don't know if its the best way to go as the query needs to be as quick as possible, also don't know how to make it work for multiple columns.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN first_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS sum_of_nulls1
    FROM (patient AS p JOIN patient_score AS s ON p.patient_id=s.patient_id);
```

Comment: `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patient WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Using `sum` in your case will force a scan - probably a table scan if many columns; using `exists` will be the better choice and likely result in far fewer logical reads.